# Incremental refresh and long downtime

Tags: powerbi

Consider this scenario: a data source with incremental refresh policy enabled, no last-update-time field, the refresh time range is 3 days, and archive is 6 months. After prolonged normal operations (i.e. all data is in place), the refresh starts to consistently fail and after a few failed attempts it gets auto-disabled by the system.  If the model remains in this disabled state for, let's say 14 days, what will happen after things get back to normal: will there be a gap in the data between day 3 and day 14, or will the service detect the gap and fill it in?

I couldn't find any documentation detailing this scenario, but just a read of the documentation seems to suggest that there will be a gap.

A pointer to some literature describing this or an account of personal experience of this situation is appreciated.